# All nodes down after Torque install

Tags: linux, hpc, torque

All nodes registering as down after new torque install.  I'm not sure why

```
[root@rbx-1 6.0.1]# pbsnodes -a
rbx-1
     state = down
     power_state = Running
     np = 1
     ntype = cluster
     mom_service_port = 15002
     mom_manager_port = 15003

rbx-2
     state = down
     power_state = Running
     np = 1
     ntype = cluster
     mom_service_port = 15002
     mom_manager_port = 15003
```

Here is qmgr says

```
[root@rbx-1 6.0.1]# qmgr -c 'p s'

create queue batch
set queue batch queue_type = Execution
set queue batch resources_default.nodes = 1
set queue batch resources_default.walltime = 01:00:00
set queue batch enabled = True
set queue batch started = True
#
# Set server attributes.
#
set server scheduling = True
set server acl_hosts = rbx-1
set server managers = root@rbx-1
set server operators = root@rbx-1
set server default_queue = batch
set server log_events = 2047
set server mail_from = adm
set server node_check_rate = 150
set server tcp_timeout = 300
set server job_stat_rate = 300
set server poll_jobs = True
set server down_on_error = True
set server mom_job_sync = True
set server keep_completed = 300
set server next_job_number = 0
set server moab_array_compatible = True
set server nppcu = 1
set server timeout_for_job_delete = 120
set server timeout_for_job_requeue = 120
```

Please help- I don't know what's causing this or what to try next.  Any ideas on tutorials or other would be helpful

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `momctl -d0 -h rbx-1` to see if the MOMs are communicating with the server. Make sure the host names in the server_name file match up with /etc/hosts on the server and the compute nodes. I'd guess you don't have the short names in /etc/hosts on the nodes.